Gauss-Quadrature proof ? (symmetric nodes)
If $2\sum_{j=0}^{n} \lambda_j f\left( x_j \right)$ is a quadrature for $\int_{-1}^{1} f\left( x \right)dx$ exact for polynomials deg$\left( f \right)\le$ n and $\lambda_j = \lambda_\left( n-j \right)$, is $x_j$ = $-x_\left( n-j \right)$ ??
I have seen this question,
If $2 \sum_{j=0}^{n}a_jf(x_j)$ is a quadrature for $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx$ exact for polynomials of degree $\le n$ and $x_j=-x_{n-j}$, show $a_j=a_{n-j}$.
whose proof was clear. I could even show it in general for arbitrary gaussian quadratures (not only Gauss-Legendre) when the weight function is even.
I believe that it also works the other way around, but unfortunately I couldn't prove it. I would be very grateful for an approach. I tried using the zeros of the orthogonal polynomial, as these determine the node points, but unfortunately I failed :/
Definition/Notation
$Q\left( f \right) = I_w \left( 1 \right)\sum_{J=0}^{n} \lambda_j f\left( x_j \right)$ and $\lambda_j=\frac{1}{I_w \left( 1 \right)}\int_{-1}^{1} l_j\left( x \right)w\left( x \right) dx$ and also $l_i(x) = \prod_{\substack{j=0 \\ j \neq i}}^{n} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j}
$ according to my definition. Also, $I_w \left( 1 \right) =\int_{-1}^{1}w\left( x \right) dx$

If we consider$n=2$, then a quadrature rule like $\lambda f(x_0) + \mu f(x_1) + \lambda f(x_2)$ will give you $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \ x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \ x_0^2 & x_1^2 & x_2^2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda \ \mu \ \lambda\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\0\2/3\end{pmatrix}$
which solves $\lambda (x_0 + x_2) + (2 - 2\lambda) x_1 = 0$ and $\lambda(x_0^2 + x_2^2) + (2-2\lambda) x_1^2 = 2/3$.
Therefore $x_1 = \frac{\lambda(x_0 + x_2)}{2\lambda - 2}$, then
$$\lambda(x_0^2 + x_2^2) + \frac{\lambda^2 (x_0+x_2)^2}{2-2\lambda} = 2/3$$
this should have solution $x_0+x_2\neq0$.

For n = 2 and the Gauss legendre quadrature, I get by using
$\left( \lambda,\mu,\lambda \right) =(\frac{10}{18},\frac{16}{18},\frac{10}{18})$ and $\left( -x_0,x_1,x_0 \right) = (-\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}},0,\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}})$ $\ast$ .$\$
$\lambda\left( 2x_0^2 \right)=2/3  \$
$\underrightarrow{\ast}$ $\frac{10}{18}\frac{6}{5}=\frac{2}{3}$

If the rule is Gaussian, then there is an easy proof. But if the rule is not Gaussian, the claim is not correct.

Let the Gauss quadrature rule
$$\int_{-1}^1 \rho(x) f(x) dx = \sum_{k=0}^n w_k f(x_k)$$
be exact for all polynomials $f$ of degree $\le 2n+1$. The weight function $\rho \ge 0$ is an even function.
It is known that the nodes $\{x_k\}_{k=0}^n$ are the roots of the orthogonal polynomials $p_{n+1}$ (we assume the leading coefficient of each $p_k$ is one).
We show the following claim:

The polynomial $p_{2k}$ is even and $p_{2k+1}$ is odd.

Proof by induction. When $k=0$, we find that $p_0 = 1$ is a constant function, so it is even and $p_1(x) = x + c$ satisfies
$$\int_{-1}^1 \rho(x) 1\cdot (x + c) dx = \int_{-1}^1 \rho(x) x dx + c\int_{-1}^1\rho(x) dx $$
Since $\rho(x)$ is even, the first term vanishes, thus $c = 0$, which means $p_1(x) = x$.
Then combine with the recurrence formula for orthogonal polynomial:
$$p_{k+1} = a_k x p_k(x) + b_k p_{k-1}$$
It is not difficult to see the claim is correct, because $x$ multiply to an even/odd polynomial generates an odd/even polynomial. The symmetry of roots is a direct conclusion of the claim.

However, if the quadrature rule is not Gaussian, having symmetric weights $w_k$ does not imply a symmetric distribution of nodes.

got it! thank you for your time and the detailed explanation :)
